# Trying to use a multidimensional hash. Also have a loop issue

Tags: ruby

Having some trouble checking for multiple sets of values.

```
loop do
  turns(player1,player2)
  break puts "you win!"  if @entries.values[0..2].all?{|move| move == "X"}
end
```

I wanted to use a multi-dimensional hash like this. Is my syntax wrong or is this just something you cannot do?

```
loop do
  turns(player1,player2)
  break puts "you win!"  if @entries.values[[0..2][3..5]].all?{|move| move =="X"}
end
```

another problem is when values[0..2] are already equal to "x" the loop doesn't break until the next turn.

Here is the repl
https://repl.it/JrQe/57

### Source code

```
@entries = {1=>" ", 2=>" ", 3=>" ", 4=>" ", 5=>" ", 6=>" ", 7=>" ", 8=>" ", 9=>" "}

puts "###########################################"
puts "                tic-tac-toe"

puts "\t\t 1 | 2 | 3 "
puts "\t\t-----------"
puts "\t\t 4 | 5 | 6 "
puts "\t\t-----------"
puts "\t\t 7 | 8 | 9 "
puts" ###########################################"

class Players
  attr_accessor :name, :piece
  end

puts "Player one, what is your name?"
player1 = Players.new
player1.name = gets.chomp
player1.piece = "X"
puts "Hello #{player1.name}, you have been assigned #{player1.piece}."

puts "Player two, what is your name?"
player2 = Players.new
player2.name = gets.chomp  
player2.piece = "O"
puts "Hello #{player2.name}, you have been assigned #{player2.piece}."

  def grid
puts "\t\t #{@entries[1]} | #{@entries[2]} | #{@entries[3]} "
puts "\t\t-----------"
puts "\t\t #{@entries[4]} | #{@entries[5]} | #{@entries[6]} "
puts "\t\t-----------"
puts "\t\t #{@entries[7]} | #{@entries[8]} | #{@entries[9]} "
end 

def choice(grid)
  name = gets.chomp
  name2 = name.to_i
    @entries.each do |key,value|
      if name2 == key 
     @entries[key]= "X"
     end
   end
 end

def choice2(grid)
  name = gets.chomp
  name2 = name.to_i
    @entries.each do |key,value|
      if name2 == key 
     @entries[key]= "O"
     end
   end
 end

def turns(player1,player2)
  puts "#{player1.name} make your move"
  player1 = choice(grid)
  puts "#{player2.name} make your move"
  player2 = choice2(grid)
end  

def win
  

loop do
  turns(player1,player2)
  break puts "you win!"  if @entries.values[0..2].all?{|move| move == "X"}
end
```

Comment: Your syntax is definitely wrong, but I can't figure out what you're trying to do... what would you expect `@entries.values[[0..2][3..5]]` to actually evaluate to? And you mention a "multi-dimensional hash" (hash of hashes), but your hash just contains strings.

Comment: As to your second question, `turns` asks both players for moves before returning, so you'll never stop the game in between players' moves. Perhaps break that up into two calls so you can check for wins in between.

Comment: It's tic tac toe. When a row of 3 hash values equal "X"(or "O") the loop should break. I'm trying to break the loop when one of the  win possibilities is true.

Comment: I guess I'll just write a different @entries.values[0..2] == "X" for every possibility and just change the value numbers. Thought I could just minimize the amount of code by doing [[0..2][3..5]]

Comment: There may be a way to do what you're trying to do, but I still don't follow what you want `[[0..2][3..5]]` to do. Which set of elements in your hash should it return? (For that matter, how *many* elements should it return?)

Comment: if [0..2] or [3..5]' or [6..8]'s value is equal to "X" break the loop and print "you win".

Comment: (Side note, does any of this even work? Unless I'm missing something, there's no key `0` in your hash, so `[0..2]` doesn't make sense, and I don't think you can index into a hash with a range like this anyway. You should probably be using an array.)

Comment: So there's *no* value that `@entries[[0..2][3..5]]` could return that would help you.

Comment: It actually does work. I originally had [1..3] until i realized 1 = 0.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed the `.values`. You basically *are* using an array (of the values in your hash).

Comment: Yes, I think I'm just going to go ahead and write out each set of values separate, I've been trying to figure out this last bit of code for a while now.

Comment: I think you should use a class for the game board. It would help organize things a bit. See [this code review question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/164100/validate-if-sudoku-is-correct/164485#164485) for an example of this approach. You may want to stop by there once you get this working :)

Comment: Using a class to represent a player is a good idea (convention is to use the singular: `Player`). However, you're not using it to its full advantage! For example, you wouldn't need to have two `choice` methods if you passed in the player and used `player.piece` instead of hardcoded values.

Comment: I totally agree with you. The idea of this project was to use classes. I just am having a tough time writing programs without my hand being held. I planned on just getting it to work however I can with as little help as possible. After I finished I was going to go back and refactor everything into classes ans separate files. My knowledge of classes isn't that great yet, so I just went with the flow and whatever worked, worked.

Comment: Sounds good! Don't worry, it was confusing to everyone at some point. Eventually it'll be second nature. Keep at it! (And don't forget to stop by Code Review for the refactoring ideas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the specific question you're asking is answered like this:

```
rows = [[0..2],[3..5],[6..8]]
cols = [[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8]]
diag = [[0,4,8],[2,4,6]]

(rows + cols + diag).any?{ |line| line.all?{ |cell| @entries[cell] == "X"} }
```

Also, you can't have two expressions, `break` and `puts` before a trailing `if` statement. Try this:

```
if ...
  puts "You win!"
  break
end
```

Comment: I tried putting it into my loop, code never breaks.

Comment: Actually it does break. Only once you have a row,col, and diag selected.

Comment: You can't put multiple expressions before an `if`. So your `break puts` is not doing what you expect. Try using a normal `if` construct.

Comment: Sorry still confused. What are the multiple expressions?

Comment: https://repl.it/JrQe/81 Something wrong with the code. It acts differently each time declaring a win.

Comment: I think it has something to do with index "0". It will break if I enter one of the combos that don't have "0". For instance if I try [1,4,7] it will work. [0..2] will not.

Comment: One problem is your diags are wrong. Should be [0,4,8] and  [2,4,6]

Comment: I fixed it. got rid of the 0's and started with 1,2,3. I guess it's a range not an index?

Comment: Ah, because your entries go from 1 to 9. They're not indexes, they're your hash keys. Yeah I missed that. Glad you figured it out!